# How to switch between USB gadget modes with statically built in drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, usb-device

Suppose the kernel is configured without modules so that a configured gadget mode like g_ether is registered during boot:

```
[    9.991448] udc 49000000.usb-otg: registering UDC driver [g_ether]
```

1. How can I dynamically change g_ether to g_mass_storage?
2. How can I configure g_ether, as soon as I want to I get the error:

> udc-core: couldn't find an available UDC or it's bus

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with **usbmodeswitch**. On specific devices you may need to know the magic code, which u can proably find in the internet

https://wiki-ubuntuusers-de.translate.goog/USB_ModeSwitch/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp (original is in german)

https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/usb-modeswitch

Comment: Considering U&L is a global site and English-only, I'd recommend you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739993/edit) the answer to point to an English resource instead of German.

Comment: I did not find a equal english version of it, its still be useful with auto-translation for understand how to use usb-modeswitch

Comment: Maybe https://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/ and https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/usb-modeswitch/usb_modeswitch.1.en.html?